# How to show table when the data from API is empty in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios

It shows error when it has no data in API, but I want the tbody to show a text using tr, my table has 3 rows, I want it to show a tr of a text like "no data" instead

Here's some of my code :

```
        <tbody>
        {
          records.map((d, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{d.id}</td>
              <td>{d.name}</td>             
              <td>
                <Link to={`/update/${d.id}`} className="btn btn-sm btn-success">Update</Link>
                <button onClick = {e => handleSubmit(d.id)} className="btn-del">Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))
        }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: You can write the condition inside tbody like this:-
<tbody>
    {records && records.length ? 
    records.map((d, i) => (
    <tr key={i}>
        <td>{d.id}</td>
        <td>{d.name}</td>
        <td>
            <Link to={`/update/${d.id}`} className="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            Update</Link>
            <button onClick = {e => handleSubmit(d.id)} className="btn btn-sm ms-1 btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ))
    :(
    <tr>
        <td>No Data available</td>
    </tr>
    )
    }
</tbody>

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this,

```
<td>{d.id ? d.id : 'no data'}</td>
<td>{d.name ? d.name : 'no data'}</td>
```

or like this,

```
         {d ? <tr key={i}>
              <td>{d.id}</td>
              <td>{d.name}</td>             
              <td>
                <Link to={`/update/${d.id}`} className="btn btn-sm btn-success">Update</Link>
                <button onClick = {e => handleSubmit(d.id)} className="btn btn-sm ms-1 btn-danger">Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr> : <tr>
                      'no data'
                  </tr>}
```

Comment: thank you but when I use the 2nd one why is it error on : ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tbody>
    {recodes.length > 0 ? <>{
      records.map((d, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td>{d.id}</td>
          <td>{d.name}</td>             
          <td>
            <Link to={`/update/${d.id}`} className="btn btn-sm btn-success">Update</Link>
            <button onClick = {e => handleSubmit(d.id)} className="btn btn-sm ms-1 btn-danger">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))
    }</> : {
<tr className="no_record text-center">
<td col={3}>
<h4>No Record Found</h4>
 </td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
```